# Understanding Webpack: why does it add these lines of javascript?

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm learning Laravel and trying to understand how to use **Laravel Mix** to bundle assets (scss and javascript).

As [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix) says:

> Laravel Mix provides a fluent API for defining Webpack build steps for
>   your Laravel application using several common CSS and JavaScript
>   pre-processors.

I thought that **Webpack** would simply concatenate all the javascript files into a single one (and optionally minify it), as it does with *.scss* files, which are compiled into CSS and merged into *public/css/app.css*.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42065159/) states:

> Webpack is a command line tool to create bundles of assets (code and
>   files). Webpack doesn't run on the server or the browser. Webpack
>   takes all your javascript files and any other assets and transforms
>   then into one huge file.

If it actually is just a building tool and *no part of it runs on the browser*, I don't understand why it adds this javascript to the top of the compiled file when I build with `npm run dev` (and what it exactly does):

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/                configurable: false,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: getter
/******/            });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

__webpack_require__(1);
module.exports = __webpack_require__(2);


/***/ }),
/* 1 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {



/***/ }),
/* 2 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

// removed by extract-text-webpack-plugin

/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```

And if I run `npm run prod`, this is the output in public/app.js:

```
!function(n){function t(e){if(r[e])return r[e].exports;var o=r[e]={i:e,l:!1,exports:{}};return n[e].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,t),o.l=!0,o.exports}var r={};t.m=n,t.c=r,t.d=function(n,r,e){t.o(n,r)||Object.defineProperty(n,r,{configurable:!1,enumerable:!0,get:e})},t.n=function(n){var r=n&&n.__esModule?function(){return n.default}:function(){return n};return t.d(r,"a",r),r},t.o=function(n,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(n,t)},t.p="",t(t.s=0)}([function(n,t,r){r(1),n.exports=r(2)},function(n,t){},function(n,t){}]);
```

This is the content of my *webpack.mix.js* file:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

And, since the *resources/assets/js/app.js* file **is empty**, I would expect also the (compiled) *public/js/app.js* to be completely empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have your school books, your calculator, your lunchbox and three granola bars, WebPack is what puts it all into one backpack so you can carry it easier.  That code is the backpack.  Even if you have nothing to put in it, it still makes a backpack.

Part of the reason for this is splitting up code that might interfere with each other if you had it in one namespace/scope. Having code in multiple files can create unintended interference if it isn't scoped right, and WebPack handles all of that using some of this code.

Yes, it compiles and minifies just like SCSS, but WebPack also adds more functionality that requires some boilerplate code.

Comment: Is there any option to remove the commenting? Because all the time it compiles, the file path will comes and it will create a conflict in `git`


`module.exports = __webpack_require__(/*! /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Projects/WAC/my_ielts_partner/resources/js/admin_panel/user/edit_admin_user.js */"./resources/js/admin_panel/user/edit_admin_user.js");`