# Why laravel-mix include webpack bootstrap code in my output js file?

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

I'm starting to use laravel-mix migrating from elixir.

The problem is that after copying my js file in the public folder it adds webpack bootstrap code.

This is my webpack.config.js file:

```
/**
 * As our first step, we'll pull in the user's webpack.mix.js
 * file. Based on what the user requests in that file,
 * a generic config object will be constructed for us.
 */
let mix = require('../src/index');

let ComponentFactory = require('../src/components/ComponentFactory');

new ComponentFactory().installAll();

require(Mix.paths.mix());

/**
 * Just in case the user needs to hook into this point
 * in the build process, we'll make an announcement.
 */

Mix.dispatch('init', Mix);

/**
 * Now that we know which build tasks are required by the
 * user, we can dynamically create a configuration object
 * for Webpack. And that's all there is to it. Simple!
 */

let WebpackConfig = require('../src/builder/WebpackConfig');

module.exports = new WebpackConfig().build();
```

my webpack.mix.js file:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for your application, as well as bundling up your JS files.
 |
 */

mix
    .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'resources/assets/css')
    .copy('resources/assets/css/app.css', 'public/css/');
```

my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "nailsacademy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "npm": "^6.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "author": "FREEDEVSOFTWARE",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  }
}
```

the original js file is:

```
function load() {

}
```

and the result file after the mix.js is:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, { enumerable: true, get: getter });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // define __esModule on exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
/******/        if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/        }
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // create a fake namespace object
/******/    // mode & 1: value is a module id, require it
/******/    // mode & 2: merge all properties of value into the ns
/******/    // mode & 4: return value when already ns object
/******/    // mode & 8|1: behave like require
/******/    __webpack_require__.t = function(value, mode) {
/******/        if(mode & 1) value = __webpack_require__(value);
/******/        if(mode & 8) return value;
/******/        if((mode & 4) && typeof value === 'object' && value && value.__esModule) return value;
/******/        var ns = Object.create(null);
/******/        __webpack_require__.r(ns);
/******/        Object.defineProperty(ns, 'default', { enumerable: true, value: value });
/******/        if(mode & 2 && typeof value != 'string') for(var key in value) __webpack_require__.d(ns, key, function(key) { return value[key]; }.bind(null, key));
/******/        return ns;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "/";
/******/
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ "./resources/assets/js/app.js":
/*!************************************!*\
  !*** ./resources/assets/js/app.js ***!
  \************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

function load() {}

/***/ }),

/***/ "./resources/assets/sass/app.scss":
/*!****************************************!*\
  !*** ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss ***!
  \****************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

// removed by extract-text-webpack-plugin

/***/ }),

/***/ 0:
/*!***************************************************************************!*\
  !*** multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss ***!
  \***************************************************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

__webpack_require__(/*! C:\xampp\htdocs\nailsacademy\resources\assets\js\app.js */"./resources/assets/js/app.js");
module.exports = __webpack_require__(/*! C:\xampp\htdocs\nailsacademy\resources\assets\sass\app.scss */"./resources/assets/sass/app.scss");


/***/ })

/******/ });
```

Why do mix process add this code?
I just want to understand if I really need it and why it's necessary.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Webpack: why does it add these lines of javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551888/understanding-webpack-why-does-it-add-these-lines-of-javascript)

Comment: I haven't found that question before.
So I think I will use copy instead of js function.
Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Is there any option to remove the commenting? Because all the time it compiles, the file path will come and it will create a conflict in the git 
```module.exports = __webpack_require__(/*! /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Projects/WAC/my_ielts_partner/resources/js/admin_panel/user/edit_admin_user.js */"./resources/js/admin_panel/user/edit_admin_user.js");```